# How to Crossjoin or Create a Cartesian Product in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Can I use power query to combine two tables, so that each rows in table 1 contains all rows in table 2.

For example table 1 includes: customer a, customer b, customer c
table 2 includes: product 1, product 2.

I want to combine two tables into table 3: customer a product 1, customer a product 2, customer b product 1, customer b product 2, customer c product 1, customer c product 2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called a Cartesian join.

Add a column to table 1 with the following code

```
= Table2
```

Then expand to new rows by clicking the arrows at the top of the column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plain vanilla, you can find a simple example in the Microsoft documentation: [Cross-Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/cross-join)